# Is there a public ajax endpoint?

Tags: ajax

I am making ajax requests and everything seems to go to admin-ajax.php. I am writing a public facing plugin and it seems strange that a user would make a request to anything with the word `admin` in it. is this just a misnomer?

Comment: The `admin-ajax.php` endpoint is publicly accessible to anyone, but the [`wp_ajax_<action>` hook](https://developer.wordpress.org/reference/hooks/wp_ajax_action/) will only run for logged-in users. So I'm not sure what exactly is the issue you're facing or trying to solve? Also, I'd suggest you to use the modern REST API where you can [create your own custom endpoint](https://developer.wordpress.org/rest-api/extending-the-rest-api/adding-custom-endpoints/) and then make your AJAX requests to that endpoint instead.

Comment: Yeah, i think that's what i'm looking for. thanks.